# vue-electron-builder plugin - passing form data from vue to main electron process

Tags: forms, vue.js, electron-builder

I'm creating a cross platform electron app using vuejs and vue-cli-electron-builder plugin. I have some input field in a form that will give to the user the ability to submit a form with some attached files and I want to process the files in the background process of the app. How I can send the data from the vue UI to the main process of the electron app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two processes in electron, the main process, and the renderer process. A Vue component runs on the renderer process. Writing files, however, runs on the main process which is usually represented by `background.js`. We need a way to communicate between these two processes to write the data. That way is called `inter-process communication`. electron provides `ipcMain` & `ipcRenderer` to communicate between the two processes.

Suppose you need to send data from the form (Vue component) to the main process. We start by defining a custom event in `background.js` such as:

```js
import {ipcMain} from "electron"; 

// this is the event listener that listens to the event emitted by the Vue component
ipcMain.on("form-submission-event", (event, args) => writeFormData(args));
```

In your Vue component, you'd do the following:

```js
import {ipcRenderer} from "electron";

export default defineComponent({
     methods: {
         submitForm(data){
           // this will send the data to the main process
          ipcRenderer.send("form-submission-event", data)
          }
     }
}
```

You could also communicate data the other way around, i.e. from the main process to the renderer process. Read more here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main and here https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer

You might get an error message like "dirname is not found". The fix to that is to add the following code to `vue.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  }
```

};

Comment: thank you for the answer, I've tried to add the `nodeIntegration` but I get this error when I run the app in serve mode `ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined`. I've tried by restarting the process but the error still remain, I'm not sure what's wrong

Comment: Which version of Vue and electron are you using? Also, are you using `npm run electron:serve`? or are you getting the error with `npm run serve`?

Comment: I'm using `vue/cli 4.3.1` and I'm creating the projects using vue ui, for the electron builder plugin I'm using the `"vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "^2.0.0-rc.5"` version that use internally electron `"electron": "^9.0.0"`. I'm using the `npm run electron:serve` command from vue ui

Comment: Ok, could you upgrade to electron 11? Maybe that would help.

Comment: I'm trying to update it globally but when I run the `electron -v` from the macOS terminal I get `v3.0.0` .I've tried to run the `npm uninstall electron && npm install electron@latest -g` but it will install always `v3.0.0` maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Inside your project directory, try `npm install electron@11.0.3`.

Comment: at the moment I've removed all the project folder and I've re created it with all files. The strange thing is that `vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder` will always install the version `^9.0.0` of electron, I've checked the online github repo and I'm not sure about but seems that the plugin is updated to install electron `v11.0.3`. I need to try by installing electron v11 as you've suggested but I'm using vue ui, so I don't know if the old version of electron will be updated ?

Comment: the `ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined` still remain also after updating electron to the latest version as a dev dependency :(

Comment: I'm so sorry! I tried this again and it works. Not sure what's going wrong with you :( Anyway, check this out https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration

Comment: Already saw it and not work in my case. I'm using `vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "^2.0.0-rc.5` I think it's a bug of this release